# Query to get all distinct lines adding a column indicating a sum of each duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, windows-server-2012

What I'm Looking for:

I need to have a list from SQL server getting all IDs, but each ID have multiples lines.
Some lines from each ID are systems update so do not need to take care about them in my query.

In another words:

**I need to get the whole list, counting all lines that are not from system for each ID.**

The Database its looks like below:

```
ID | linenumber| data, data, ... data|Requesto| data, data

1  | 1         |.....................|JUAN    |...........
1  | 2         |.....................|SYSTEM  |...........
2  | 1         |.....................|Matias  |...........
2  | 2         |.....................|Matias  |...........
2  | 3         |.....................|Matias  |...........
```

And I need to get:

```
ID | CantRoWs  |.....................|WHO is  |...........

1  | 1         |.....................|JUAN    |...........
2  | 3         |.....................|Matias  |...........
```

I was thinking about using a temp query like below but it does not work.

```
with temp as
    (
      SELECT OVER (PARTITION BY szCID ORDER BY gdReceived desc) as RowNum,*
      FROM TABLE1;
    )
    SELECT *, (Select count(szCID) from TABLE1 where szAccount <> 'system') AS Hits From temp 
    WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is too much hidden detail. What are ALL the "data, data" columns?

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: The rest of the data is not relevant at this point. I mean it's not necesarry know it to understand the question i'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start by using row_number() and count() inside the common table expression:

```
WITH temp
AS (
    SELECT
        *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY szCID ORDER BY gdReceived DESC) AS RowNum
      , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY szCID) as hits
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE szAccount <> 'system'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM temp
WHERE RowNum = 1
```